# How get array from string

Tags: c#, .net

I have sting whith int like this

```
[[1, 2],[2, 3, 4, 6],[4, 5, 6],8]
```

How convert this string to list or array like this

```
int[] a = { 1, 2 };
int[] b = { 2, 3, 4,6 };
int[] c = { 4, 5, 6 };
int d = 8;
```

i can only get 1 string

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(dataFromFile, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(line);
            }
        }
       //list.count = 1
```

Comment: You should add some code to show your effort.

Comment: We're going to need more information than what you've provided us.  Is your string always limited to the 4 sub-strings you have displayed and is the last one always a single element?  Can the string contain any number of sub-strings with any number of elements in each sub-string? If a sub-string only contains one element, do you really want it in an int or can it be in an int[] that only has one element?

Comment: last element is always 1 number
and i can get 1 string, but inside the arrays are different in length
as seen rahmer 2-4-3

Comment: So a straight forward and simple approach would be to first remove the starting [ and ending ]. Then split the string on ]. This will now give us an array of strings that still have their starting [ and comma separated. Then all you gotta do is iterate over it, replace the [ and , with an empty string and then you can iterate over that string (which returns characters), convert them to an int, and add them to your new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, this is a pretty primitive way of doing it, I am sure using LINQ or something like that would be faster; but at this time I can't quite think of a way (the joys of being at work)

```
var myArray = "[[1, 2],[2, 3, 4, 6],[4, 5, 6],8]";
        myArray = myArray.Remove(0, 1);
        myArray = myArray.Remove(myArray.Length-1);

        var test = myArray.Split(']');

        var myList = new List<List<int>>();

        foreach(var t in test) {
            var newString = t.Replace("[", "");
            newString = newString.Replace(",", "");
            var internalList = new List<int>();

            foreach(var ch in newString) {
                if(ch != ' ') {
                    var result = Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString());
                    internalList.Add(result);
                }
            }

            myList.Add(internalList);
        }
```

So now you have a List of Lists, of length 4 (so that is it has 4 lists inside of it), and you can easily iterate over said lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq`, Like the following code:

```
string input = "[[1, 2],[2, 3, 4, 6],[4, 5, 6],8]";

List<int[]> listOfArray = 
 // replace "[" by empty
 input.Replace("[", "")
    //split first by "]," and substring by "]"
    .Split(new string[] { "],", "]" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    // split by ",", and convert string to int
    .Select(x => x.Split(',').Select(y => int.Parse(y)).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

I hope this help